# UIImageView image is stretching when i am using rounded corners.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am using UITableViewCell as UITableView Header. I am using the below code to make rounded corners for UIImageView.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section==0){

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ContactDetailsHeaderTableViewCell";

    ContactDetailsHeaderTableViewCell *cell = (ContactDetailsHeaderTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactDetailsHeaderTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    ..................
    .................

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];

        //rounded corners
        cell.profilePicImgView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.profilePicImgView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);

        // Add a clip before drawing anything, in the shape of an rounded rect
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.profilePicImgView.bounds
                                    cornerRadius:60.0] addClip];
        // Draw your image
        [img drawInRect:cell.profilePicImgView.bounds];

        // Get the image, here setting the UIImageView image
        cell.profilePicImgView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        // end drawing
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


.............
.............
}
```

Below is the output

[image]

The image inside the UIImageView is stretching, if i am not using the rounded corners then the image is looking properly. I have tried lot of code sample from StackOverflow but none of them are working.

Comment: Have u tried adding `contentMode` to UIImageView? Moreover this is not even a perfect circle.

Comment: Yes, I have tried various contentModes like AspectFit,AspectFill,ScaleToFill but nothing is working.

Comment: You just want to show ImageView as a circle ? Why are you using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions then, you can make ImageView corner radius = imageview.width * 0.5 and make sure ImageView has ratio of 1:1 and also play with content mode to get the best out of it.

Comment: You can give circular shape with this also
`imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.width/2`

Comment: You are re-writing the image graphic context as per the image view, thats why `.contentMode` is not working. Simply download the image over image view and set `.contentMode`.

Comment: Got Output @Madhu ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, posting the answer so it may help others. Its not related to rounded corners code. The rounded corners code is working fine. In UIImagePickerController i have set `allowsEditing = YES` but in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` i was using `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` so later i changed it to `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`. Now its working fine. I am able to get the rounded corners image without any stretch.

```
-(void)capturePhoto{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                                    picker.delegate = self;
                                    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
                                    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

                                    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


/* earlier i have used UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage in the place of UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage so it was not working properly*/
        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

        ............
        ............





     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem in your code is that you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to dequeue headers. You should use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` instead, and base your header views on the designated class `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. They are separate classes and are recycled differently when you navigate the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that your image is not perfectly round thats why it looks like stretched image.

The issue is in following line...

```
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.profilePicImgView.bounds
                                cornerRadius:60.0] addClip];
```

> Here you are setting `cornerRadius:`, if you want image view in complete round shape then your need to set `cornerRadius:` to `cell.profilePicImgView.bounds.height/2` or may be `.width/2`.

You can make round corner in another way as below...

```
cell.profilePicImgView.image = //set image here

//Make image view round shape
cell.profilePicImgView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePicImgView.bounds.height/2

//clip the bounds of image view
cell.profilePicImgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I have already tried the above code but its not working. UIImageView behaves differently inside UITableView

Comment: just call `cell.layoutIdNeeded` before setting data.

Answer (score 0):

Is your UIImageView is of fixed size?
Please check it the same. If not given fixed size, then you need to give cornerRadius of your ImageView as `cell.profilePicImgView.bounds.height/2`.
Also try to give contentMode = AspectFill.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making image round? You should make imageview round and you're done. You not need to do anything with image!

to make image view round you need to set it'e corner radius like,

```
 yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourImageView.frame.size.height/2;
 yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
 yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageHere"];
```

Make sure that your image view's height and width is equal I mean it must be square to get exact round.

Second thing your approach to create header is wrong! You are dequeuing tableview cell in `viewForHeaderInSection`. This is wrong! Instead of this take or create one view (as xib or you can add view in storyboard beneath the main view) or create view programmatically and add your image view in that view and return that view from `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Answer (score 0):

use this  for rounding corner the image by increasing and decreasing the value as i am using small image currently borderColor is white

```
  -(UIImageView*)SetupLayoutsImg:(UIImageView*)img{

UIColor* borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:244.0/255.0f green:244.0/255.0f blue:244.0/255.0f alpha:1.0/1.0f];
int borderwidth=1.0f;
int bottomViewRadius=10.0f;

img.layer.cornerRadius = bottomViewRadius; // this value vary as per your desire
img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

img.layer.borderWidth=borderwidth;
img.layer.borderColor=borderColor.CGColor;
img.clipsToBounds = YES;

   return img;
 }


 -(UIButton*)SetupLayoutsButtons:(UIButton*)Btn{

 UIColor* borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:244.0/255.0f green:244.0/255.0f blue:244.0/255.0f alpha:1.0/1.0f];
int borderwidth=1.0f;
int buttonRadius=25.0f;

Btn.layer.cornerRadius = buttonRadius; // this value vary as per your desire

Btn.layer.borderWidth=borderwidth;
Btn.layer.borderColor=borderColor.CGColor;
Btn.clipsToBounds = YES;

   return Btn;
 }
```

How to use it by just calling it in uitableView delegate viewForHeaderInSection i am  using it in cellForRowAtIndexPath like this

```
tableCellinside.cateImage=[self SetupLayoutsImg:tableCellinside.cateImage];
```

cateImage is my UIImageView you can use it like this s

```
cell.profilePicImgView=[self SetupLayoutsImg:cell.profilePicImgView];
```